# ASP.NET Core 3.1 AWS Lambda Swagger definition not working when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Having the below code to configure in Startup.cs

Variables.

```
private const string SwaggerDocumentVersionName = "v1";
private static string SwaggerDocumentServiceName => $"Users API({SwaggerDocumentVersionName})";
```

`ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerDoc(
         SwaggerDocumentVersionName, 
               new OpenApiInfo
               {
                   Title = SwaggerDocumentServiceName,
                   Version = $"{SwaggerDocumentVersionName}"
               });
});
```

`Configure` method.

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger/ui";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{SwaggerDocumentVersionName}/swagger.json", SwaggerDocumentServiceName);
});
```

When running locally (`https://localhost:5001/swagger/ui` resolved to `https://localhost:5001/swagger/ui/index.html`) definition is loaded correctly and everything seems fine.

Deploying the service to AWS Lambda as ASP.NET Core REST API and navigating to the URL (`https://DNS_URL/API_PREFIX/swagger/ui` resolved to `https://DNS_URL/API_PREFIX/swagger/ui/index.html`)it shows the below error loading the JSON definition.

[image: Swagger JSON Definition Error]

The interesting part is that if you navigate to the JSON definition route (`https://DNS_URL/API_PREFIX/swagger/v1/swagger.json`) it shows the definition.

Comment: You swagger hosted on Lambda is most likely calling `https://DNS_URL/swagger/v1/swagger.json` (without the prefix) - which returns 404, therefore its not loading, you will have to configure swagger prefix for `production` build

Comment: @kebek not sure I understand what that means, do you see some misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main URL for the API you have released on lambda is `https://DNS_URL/API_PREFIX/`

Swagger UI needs to fetch the swagger.json file in order for it to work, and for your localhost it is working correctly since `https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json` is a valid endpoint

(*you have no prefix here)

And the version deployed to lambda is trying to fetch this `swagger.json` file under

`https://DNS_URL/swagger/v1/swagger.json` - without your `API_PREFIX`, thus it's returning 404, not found and swagger ui is displaying the Error message.

Quick fix, which you might apply, that I think would work:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger/ui";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{env.IsDevelopment() ? "" : API_PREFIX}/swagger/{SwaggerDocumentVersionName}/swagger.json", SwaggerDocumentServiceName);
});
```

Where the `API_PREFIX` is a string starting with '/'

Comment: I tried this yesterday but it looks like I was most probably missed the "/". It works fine now.